# Hölder continuity of Brownian Sheet/Wiener Field

Tags: probability, continuity, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, holder-spaces

It is known from P. Lévy, Théorie de l’addition des variables aléatoires. Monographies des Probabilités ; calcul des probabilités et ses applications 1, Paris (1937), that the sample paths of the Wiener process $W=\left(W_t\right)_{t \geq 0}$ satisfy almost surely the following Hölder condition, for sufficiently small $|t^{\prime}-t|$,

$$\left|W_{t^{\prime}}-W_t\right| \leq c \cdot \sqrt{\left|t^{\prime}-t\right| \log \left(1+\frac{1}{\left|t^{\prime}-t\right|}\right)}$$

I wonder if there is a generalisation of this result for brownian sheet/Wiener field ? More precisely, for $W=\left(W_{t_{1},...,t_{d}}\right)_{t_{1}\geq 0,...,t_{d}\geq 0}$ the $d-$fold Wiener field, do we have almost surely, for sufficiently small $\left\|(t^{'}_{1},...,t^{'}_{d})-(t_{1},...,t_{d})\right\|$,

$$\left|W_{t^{'}_{1},...,t^{'}_{d}}-W_{t_{1},...,t_{d}}\right| \leq c \cdot \sqrt{\left\|(t^{'}_{1},...,t^{'}_{d})-(t_{1},...,t_{d})\right\| \log \left(1+\frac{1}{\left\|(t^{'}_{1},...,t^{'}_{d})-(t_{1},...,t_{d})\right\|}\right)}$$

PS : Does this result hold in expectation too (even in the d=1 case) ? More precisely, do
$$\sup_{t,t^{'}\in[0,1]^{d}}\frac{\left|W_{t^{'}_{1},...,t^{'}_{d}}-W_{t_{1},...,t_{d}}\right|}{\sqrt{\left\|(t^{'}_{1},...,t^{'}_{d})-(t_{1},...,t_{d})\right\| \log \left(1+\frac{1}{\left\|(t^{'}_{1},...,t^{'}_{d})-(t_{1},...,t_{d})\right\|}\right)}}$$
admits finite moments ?

Comment: Some remarks: 0) the number 2 under the square root is quite irrelevant, as you still have some $c$ in front of it; 1) the "constant" $c$ is random; 2) you might want to add 1 inside the logarithm for technical accuracy (otherwise the inequality obviously fails for $|t'-t|=1$); 3) yes, this is true. 

Concerning your PS, you have to clarify what do you mean by "holding in expectation". Actually, the expectations of increments are less (just square root withouth the logarithm). What you might be looking at is the integrability of $c$. Yes, it has all moments (even exponential moments) finite.

Comment: @zhoraster thank you. I made a few edits corresponding to your remarks 0) and 2). Do you know any references that prove 3) ?

Comment: Also, I have seen that brownian motion/sheet are almost surely $\alpha$- Hölder (and the corresponding Hölder admits all its moment), for all $\alpha<1/2$ through Kolmogorov theorem. But not for $\alpha=1/2$. Hence, I am not sure to understand your last remark, do you mean that the supremum of the increments divided by just the square root is integrable ? This would imply that, almost surely, the sample paths are $1/2$- Hölder (as the Hölder constant will be almost surely finite) which is clearly false.

Comment: @zhoraster I am sorry, I think I get what you meant. You were talking about expectation of increments for fixed $t$ and $t'$, right ? I have modified my PS, I hope it is clearer.

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the first question: this follows from the fact that
$$
\mathrm E |W(t') - W(t)|^2 \le ||t'-t||,
$$
see e.g. Lifshitz *Gaussian Random Functions*, p. 220.

Existence of all moments follows from the Fernique theorem. Loosely it can be formulated as follows: if $X$ is centered Gaussian, and $||\cdot||$ is a seminorm such that $||X||<\infty$ almost surely, then there exists some $\alpha>0$ such that $\mathrm E e^{\alpha ||X||^2} <\infty$.
Here you can take $X = W$,  $||x|| = \sup\limits_{t'\neq t}\frac{|x(t') - x(t)|}{\big(|t'-t| \log (1 + |t'
-t|^{-1})\big)^{1/2}}$.

Comment: Thank you ! Perfect.